# Could someone explain basic transferFrom functionality

Tags: erc-20

It seems to me that the following ERC20 function does not check where the message comes from and allow anyone to transfer tokens between two addresses:

```solidity
function transferFrom (address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)
public delegatable payable returns (bool) {
  if (frozen) return false;
  else if (
    (addressFlags [_from] | addressFlags [_to]) & BLACK_LIST_FLAG ==
    BLACK_LIST_FLAG)
    return false;
  else {
    uint256 fee =
      (addressFlags [_from] | addressFlags [_to]) & ZERO_FEE_FLAG == ZERO_FEE_FLAG ?
        0 :
        calculateFee (_value);

    if (_value <= allowances [_from][msg.sender] &&
        fee <= safeSub (allowances [_from][msg.sender], _value) &&
        _value <= accounts [_from] &&
        fee <= safeSub (accounts [_from], _value)) {
      require (AbstractToken.transferFrom (_from, _to, _value));
      require (AbstractToken.transferFrom (_from, feeCollector, fee));
      return true;
    } else return false;
  }
}
```

In AbstractToken:

```solidity
function transferFrom (address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)
public payable returns (bool success) {
  uint256 spenderAllowance = allowances [_from][msg.sender];
  if (spenderAllowance < _value) return false;
  uint256 fromBalance = accounts [_from];
  if (fromBalance < _value) return false;

  allowances [_from][msg.sender] =
    safeSub (spenderAllowance, _value);

  if (_value > 0 && _from != _to) {
    accounts [_from] = safeSub (fromBalance, _value);
    accounts [_to] = safeAdd (accounts [_to], _value);
  }
  Transfer (_from, _to, _value);
  return true;
}
```

Here are the approve functions

```solidity
function approve (address _spender, uint256 _value)
public delegatable payable returns (bool success) {
  return AbstractToken.approve (_spender, _value);
}
```

In AbstractToken:

```solidity
function approve (address _spender, uint256 _value)
public payable returns (bool success) {
  allowances [msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
  Approval (msg.sender, _spender, _value);

  return true;
}
```

Is that true ? I see a `frozen` variable, which seems to me the only way to control who transfers what and when.

Comment: The `allowances` variable (table) is the one controlling who can transfer from who and how much. That variable can be configured via function `approve`, not shown in your code.

Comment: True, there is not much inside them, but I've added them. Thank you.

Comment: So what's your question then?

Comment: I want to be taught how this contract checks that the caller is allowed to issue a transferFrom since I see no control. `approve()` does no checks, it just sets values and emits Approval.

Comment: Function `approve` sets the `allowances` table, which determines who is allowed to transfer, on behalf of whom he is allowed to transfer, and the amount that he is allowed transfer.

Comment: Oh yeah msg.sender is actually used here !  I missed it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, added that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allowances` variable (table) is the one controlling who can transfer from who and how much.

This variable can be configured via function `approve`.

For example, if you sign the transaction `erc20Token.approve(myAccount, 100)` with your private key and then send it to the blockchain, then the value of `allowances[yourAccount][myAccount]` in the `erc20Token` contract will change from 0 to 100, and I will be permitted to transfer up to 100 wei tokens from your account to anywhere I want.

Answer (score 2):

There are several checks performed.  Let me explain them one by one:

```solidity
if (frozen) return false;
```

If all transfers are frozen now, just return `false`.

```solidity
if ((addressFlags [_from] | addressFlags [_to]) & BLACK_LIST_FLAG == BLACK_LIST_FLAG)
  return false;
```

If either `_from` or `_to` is in black list, return `false`.

```solidity
_value <= allowances [_from][msg.sender] &&
fee <= safeSub (allowances [_from][msg.sender], _value)
```

The owner of `_from` address explicitly allowed `msg.sender` to transfer `_value + fee` of the owner's tokens.

```solidity
_value <= accounts [_from] &&
fee <= safeSub (accounts [_from], _value)
```

The owner of `_from` address has at least `_value + fee` tokens.

```solidity
uint256 spenderAllowance = allowances [_from][msg.sender];
if (spenderAllowance < _value) return false;
```

The owner of `_from` address explicitly allowed `msg.sender` to transfer `_value` of the owner's tokens, or just return `false`.

```solidity
uint256 fromBalance = accounts [_from];
if (fromBalance < _value) return false;
```

The owner of `_from` address has at least `_value + fee` tokens, or just return `false`.

So it checked twice, that the caller was explicitly allowed by the owner of the tokens to transfer them.

BTW, I'm the author of this code.

Comment: I've set the other answer as accepted because the allowances[msg.sender] was the bit I overlooked, and it helped me to see it, and posted first, but thank you very much for those details. I like your code !